# Can we use multiple scope in SSRS's Previous function

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

As I want to use my first scope value in third scope to compare it with third scope value.? How can I achieve this.. so that i can compare first's scope value in the third scope.
For eg .. PREVIOUS(expression, "XYZ","ABC")

Comment: Read the MS documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-previous-function?view=sql-server-ver15

You cannot use more than one scope. Explain what you are trying to achieve, with exmaples and somebody may be able to offer a different approach

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.